# Same code difference display result between xib and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xib

I want to rotate a view loaded from xib,but the result is not what i want.
[image: xib effect]

But when i made a demo with storyboard,it's the result what i want.
[image: storyboard effect]

And this is the code:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -10*M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1);
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -5, 0, 0);
self.view1.layer.transform = transform;

CATransform3D transform1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform1 = CATransform3DRotate(transform1, 10*M_PI/180, 0, 0, 1);
transform1 = CATransform3DTranslate(transform1, 5, 0, 0);
self.view2.layer.transform = transform1;
```

Both xib and storyboard used autoresizingMask,the left view(Brown color) used `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` and the right view(Pink color) used `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`.